# I want to decouple my SpringBoot application from the database it uses. Application fails to start without connection

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm using a SpringBoot application that serves the purpose of interacting with a thirdparty API for the endusers. As a secondary objective this application should also log certain requests going through the application - this is only secondary though, and the application should be able to run even if the database is unavailable.

The problem we face is that by using the default spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency, the application is unable to start if the database is unavailable..

We want these to be decoupled, so that the application will still run even if the database is unavailable, so that it can serve it's primary purpose, and retry to establish the database connection..

Here is some further technical details:

Spring version: 2.2.1

Dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
```

Controller class:

```
@RestController
public class RekvisisjonRESTController {
    
    @Autowired
    RekvisisjonService rekvisisjonService;

    @Autowired
    LoggingService loggingService;

    @GetMapping("/api/v1/rekvisisjoner/{reknr}")
    public Rekvisisjon getRekvisisjon(@PathVariable String reknr, @RequestParam String type,
        @RequestParam String personId) throws GatewayException {
        var rekvisisjon = rekvisisjonService.getRekvisisjon(reknr, type, personId);
        loggingService.logDetalj(Long.parseLong(reknr));
        return rekvisisjon;
    }
    // Other methods
}
```

application.properties:

```
# MYSQL CONFIGURATION
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://qx-henny-db0001.q.no:3306/requis
spring.datasource.username=rekvisys_user
spring.datasource.password=${docker-secret-rek_db_password}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Error message:
The password is set wrong to illustrate that the application wont run if the connection cant be established

```
rekv.1.3lsi20xbkn6f@t-atom-srv0002.test.ld.nhn.no    | {"@timestamp":"2021-02-01T21:22:45.407Z","@version":"1","level":"INFO","message":"HikariPool-1 - Starting...","logger_name":"com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource","thread_name":"main","application_name":"Rekvisisjon"}
rekv.1.3lsi20xbkn6f@t-atom-srv0002.test.ld.nhn.no    | {"@timestamp":"2021-02-01T21:22:45.489Z","@version":"1","level":"ERROR","message":"HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.","logger_name":"com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool","thread_name":"main","application_name":"Rekvisisjon","stack_trace":"java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'rekvisys_user'@'t-atom-srv0002.test.ld.nhn.no' (using password: YES)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke(<generated>)\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f2b3a156.getConnection(<generated>)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)\n\tat org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)\n\tat org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)\n\tat org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)\n\tat org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)\n\tat org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)\n\tat org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)\n\tat org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)\n\tat org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)\n\tat org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175)\n\tat org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)\n\tat org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1214)\n\tat org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1245)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)\n\tat no.pasientreiser.atom.rekvisisjon.RekvisisjonApplication.main(RekvisisjonApplication.java:14)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)\n"}
rekv.1.3lsi20xbkn6f@t-atom-srv0002.test.ld.nhn.no    | {"@timestamp":"2021-02-01T21:22:45.490Z","@version":"1","level":"WARN","message":"HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Access denied for user 'rekvisys_user'@'t-atom-srv0002.test.ld.nhn.no' (using password: YES)","logger_name":"org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator","thread_name":"main","application_name":"Rekvisisjon"}
rekv.1.3lsi20xbkn6f@t-atom-srv0002.test.ld.nhn.no    | {"@timestamp":"2021-02-01T21:22:45.507Z","@version":"1","level":"INFO","message":"HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect","logger_name":"org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect","thread_name":"main","application_name":"Rekvisisjon"}
rekv.1.3lsi20xbkn6f@t-atom-srv0002.test.ld.nhn.no    | {"@timestamp":"2021-02-01T21:22:46.789Z","@version":"1","level":"INFO","message":"HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.18.Final","logger_name":"org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version","thread_name":"main","application_name":"Rekvisisjon"}
rekv.1.3lsi20xbkn6f@t-atom-srv0002.test.ld.nhn.no    | {"@timestamp":"2021-02-01T21:22:49.121Z","@version":"1","level":"INFO","message":"HikariPool-1 - Starting...","logger_name":"com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource","thread_name":"main","application_name":"Rekvisisjon"}
rekv.1.3lsi20xbkn6f@t-atom-srv0002.test.ld.nhn.no    | {"@timestamp":"2021-02-01T21:22:49.123Z","@version":"1","level":"ERROR","message":"HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.","logger_name":"com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool","thread_name":"main","application_name":"Rekvisisjon","stack_trace":"java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'rekvisys_user'@'t-atom-srv0002.test.ld.nhn.no' (using password: YES)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke(<generated>)\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)\n\tatorg.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f2b3a156.getConnection(<generated>)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43)\n\tat org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60)\n\tat org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:67)\n\tat org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:333)\n\tat org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:120)\n\tat org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratororg.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:320)\n\tat org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)\n\tat org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)\n\tat no.pasientreiser.atom.rekvisisjon.RekvisisjonApplication.main(RekvisisjonApplication.java:14)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)\n"}
rekv.1.3lsi20xbkn6f@t-atom-srv0002.test.ld.nhn.no    | {"@timestamp":"2021-02-01T21:22:49.188Z","@version":"1","level":"WARN","message":"SQL Error: 1045, SQLState: 28000","logger_name":"org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper","thread_name":"main","application_name":"Rekvisisjon"}
rekv.1.3lsi20xbkn6f@t-atom-srv0002.test.ld.nhn.no    | {"@timestamp":"2021-02-01T21:22:49.189Z","@version":"1","level":"ERROR","message":"Access denied for user 'rekvisys_user'@'t-atom-srv0002.test.ld.nhn.no' (using password: YES)","logger_name":"org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper","thread_name":"main","application_name":"Rekvisisjon"}
rekv.1.3lsi20xbkn6f@t-atom-srv0002.test.ld.nhn.no    | {"@timestamp":"2021-02-01T21:22:49.194Z","@version":"1","level":"WARN","message":"Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext","thread_name":"main","application_name":"Rekvisisjon"}
rekv.1.3lsi20xbkn6f@t-atom-srv0002.test.ld.nhn.no    | {"@timestamp":"2021-02-01T21:22:49.196Z","@version":"1","level":"INFO","message":"Stopping service [Tomcat]","logger_name":"org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService","thread_name":"main","application_name":"Rekvisisjon"}
rekv.1.3lsi20xbkn6f@t-atom-srv0002.test.ld.nhn.no    | {"@timestamp":"2021-02-01T21:22:49.292Z","@version":"1","level":"INFO","message":"\n\nError starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener","thread_name":"main","application_name":"Rekvisisjon"}
failed","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","thread_name":"main","application_name":"Rekvisisjon","stack_trace":"org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)\n\tat no.pasientreiser.atom.rekvisisjon.RekvisisjonApplication.main(RekvisisjonApplication.java:14)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)\nCaused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799)\n\t... 24 common frames omitted\nCaused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution\n\tat org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:69)\n\tat org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60)\n\tat org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:67)\n\tat org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:333)\n\tat org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:120)\n\tat org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:65)\n\tat org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)\n\tat org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)\n\tat org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)\n\tat org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:320)\n\tat org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)\n\tat org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)\n\t... 28 common frames omitted\nCaused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'rekvisys_user'@'t-atom-srv0002.test.ld.nhn.no' (using password: YES)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke(<generated>)\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f2b3a156.getConnection(<generated>)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43)\n\t... 43 common frames omitted\n"}
```